# MongoDB timeout when query includes !==

Tags: c#, mongodb, mapreduce

I am running a mapreduce to generate a report on newsletter activity.

To run the report for a specific newsletter I use:

```
var query = Query.And(
                    Query.EQ("NewsletterId", BsonInt32.Create(newsletterId)),
                    Query.GTE("DateAdded", BsonDateTime.Create(startDate)).LTE(BsonDateTime.Create(endDate))
                );
```

I now want to be able to get an aggregate report of email activity on all of the newsletters (using the same mapreduce, but just changing the query). For this I use:

```
var query = Query.And(
                    Query.Where(new BsonJavaScript("this.NewsletterId !== null")),
                    Query.GTE("DateAdded", BsonDateTime.Create(startDate)).LTE(BsonDateTime.Create(endDate))
                        );
```

I have an index set which includes the NewsletterId and DateAdded, which I think is being used in the first query, but not the second one, which is causing it to timeout.

Any sort of optimization I can make to prevent the query from timing out?

Comment: Well.. with Less than or equal there will be fewer records to scan than with not equal in almost all cases.  How long does the first query take to deliver results, and after how long is the second query timing out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `$exists` conditional instead. (`Exists()` in the 10gen C# driver)

In MongoDB, `$where` will be slow with large collections. By nature it doesn't use an index. It simply deserializes each object and evaluates your clause.

For the purpose of completeness, if your date range contains relatively few documents, you may be able to optimize this well enough by switching the order of the components in your `$and` clause. That way you'll be running the slow operation on the records in the date range, instead of running a slow operation on *all* the records.